# docker stack ignoring unsupported options

Tags: docker, db2

I am running docker Server Version: 18.06.0-ce on centos 7.5.

I have a docker-compose file running db2 server with the following sample definition:

The docker-compose file has the following options:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
    db2exp:
        image: db2
        ports:
            - "50000:50000"
        networks:
            - lmnet
        ipc: host
        cap_add:
            - IPC_LOCK
            - IPC_OWNER
        environment:
            - DB2INSTANCE=db2inst1
            - DB2PASSWD=db2inst1
            - LICENSE=accept
        volumes:
            - db2data:/home
```

When using docker-compose up, I do not have problems with starting the db2 service. However when I try to use docker stack, I get the following message:

```
docker stack deploy test --compose-file docker-compose.yml
Ignoring unsupported options: cap_add, ipc
```

This renders db2start to return SQL1042C  An unexpected system error occurred.

It would be ideal if what runs in compose runs in stack.  What, if any, can be done so that the db2 container can be used in a docker stack environment and not just docker-compose?

If it matters, I have docker-compose version 1.23.0-rc1, build 320e4819.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Revised the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is not supported by swarm mode currently as the error message you've show and documentation identify. Personally I'd question whether you really want to have your database running in swarm mode. Docker does not migrate the volume for you, so you wouldn't see your data if rescheduled on another node.

You can follow the progress of getting this added to Swarm Mode in the github issues, there are several, including:

- https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/24862
- https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25885

The hacky solution I've seen if you really need this run from swarm mode is to schedule a container with the docker socket mounted and docker binaries in the image, which then executes a docker run command directly against the local engine. E.g.:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
    db2exp-wrapper:
        image: docker:stable
        volumes:
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
        command: docker run --rm --cap-add IPC_LOCK --cap-add IPC_OWNER -p 50000:50000 ... db2
```

I don't really recommend the above solution, sticking with docker-compose would likely be a better implementation for your use case. Downsides of this solution include only publishing the port on the single host, and potential security risks of anyone else with access to that docker socket.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I was hoping to be able to run in stack so I can run the other multiple instances of the services that depend on the db2 server. I will keep a close eye on the github issues that you shared.

Comment: @sj177 You can't use `depends_on` in swarm either. But you can make overlay networks attachable, and connect to an external network from either compose or swarm, to get services communications.

Comment: I figured the depends_on does not work even in compose. It only starts services in order but does not pay attention to the application being ready. I put in necessary waits in the entrypoint for dependent services. Thanks again.

Comment: Very interesting bit on the validity (or lack thereof) of using a swarm for a database service, instead of a simple compose. I wonder where to turn to so as to learn more about this. Like what type of service would be fit for a swarm or a compose..